# Absolute value of an element in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Is absolute value of a partial isometry a partial isometry itself?

Comment: $V$ is a partial isometry if V*V is a projection. Absolute value is defined by $(V*V)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Yes. If $p$ is a projection, $p^\frac{1}{2}=p$ is a partial isometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, as square roots are self-adjoint $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$ 
\begin{align*}
  \abs v^*\abs v &= [(v^*v)^{1/2}]^*(v^*v)^{1/2}\\
              &= (v^*v)^{1/2}(v^*v)^{1/2}\\
              &= v^*v
\end{align*}